# I want to resize /dev/sda2 ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, partition, gparted

[image: Image from GParted]

Hi every one i need help i can't shrink /dev/sda2 and make free space
Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Ext4 cannot be shrunk when mounted, you need to run GParted from a LiveCD to be able to resize it. Make sure to make a backup of your data first.